# Macros not showing up in the run macro menu

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I started learning VBA and I don't understand why some macros copy-pasted from the internet do not show up in the run macro menu (Alt-F8).

Below there are 2 macros, but only the second one is showing. Why? And how do I fix it?

```
Sub Test1(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    '...

End Sub

Sub Test2()

    '...

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Macros with arguments are not available in Macros list because they cannot be run alone instead they are called by another macro by passing the required arguments.

Comment: @sktneer If you post it as answer, I will approve it

Comment: Done! Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros with arguments are not available in Macros list because they cannot be run alone instead they are called by another macro by passing the required arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If a `Sub` declaration contains parameters it will not show there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call macros that have parameters as you are describing. If you need to have a parameter, you can take it out and then have the user input the value.

```
Sub Test1()        
    Dim hyperLink As String
    hyperLink = InputBox("Please input hyperlink", "My Parameter")

    '...

End Sub
```

Alternatively, if the hyperlink is in your document, grab the value from your document instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 5 cents - if you give an **optional parameter**, you will be able to call the sub routine, even if it will not be shown among the ones which you can chose from.

Write `aaaaTestMe` and press <kbd>Run</kbd>.

```
Public Sub aaaaTestMe(Optional lngA As Long = 8)
    Debug.Print lngA
End Sub
```

Comment: @james the most convenient way I know is to call it from the Immediate window - press **Ctrl + G** and write there `aaaaTestMe 31`

Answer (score 1):

You can call an even private macro from any excel object you can assign a macro, calling it this way:

'MyWorkbook'!'MyModule.MyProcedure "MyParameter1"'

(be careful with single quotes: ' around procedure name with parameter)