# VBA to change background color of exel cell if value of any cell in sheet is deleted or updated

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I am working on pre populated excel sheet with data in every cell ,
I am looking to a macro or conditional formatting or formula which will change the color of any cell of that sheet where the contents of the cells are either edited or deleted or changed ?

regards

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: You need to try google and ask a concrete question where you get stuck

Comment: i have tried nothing found matching with my specific requirement mentioned above which is pretty simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen said you need a worksheet_change event for it. This is fairly easy to search for and I can find multiple similar questions on it.

Since it's so simple though, pop this code into your sheet module. Change the yellow to what color or search for the other methods to change cell colors in VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Target.Cells.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

Comment: hi Simon , thanks , but when i am using this code, its not showing up in the macro run dialogue , I have tried searching for solution and found this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922417/macros-not-showing-up-in-the-run-macro-menu)  i can understand that I need another sub ( lets call caller's sub = sub A)  which will  call Worksheet_Change but what should I put as an argument to Worksheet_change (?) when calling Worksheet_Change.  ? i mean Target and Range . My worksheet is called " Sheet1" and range is A1 to C100 ,  I am really new to this

Comment: You don't add it to any other sub. When you put the Worksheet_Change sub in your sheet module, any time anything gets changed in that sheet, this macro automatically runs. So open visual basic and open your "Sheet1" module. Paste all of my answer code into it, then go back to your sheet and change something. It should automatically change colour.

Comment: Great thanks its working , but currently its changing the color on every single operation even when i select any cell , i want to prevent that, i just want the color to be changed when user edit the cell value or delete the cell value  is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: It definitely shouldn't. What I posted will only change cells that have been edited or deleted. You have the sub called `Worksheet_Change` not `Worksheet_SelectionChange` right? Because SelectionChange will run everytime you click a different cell.

Comment: sorry my bad, you are right its working fine as i used selectionChange.. thanks a bunch ...!! have a great weekend ahead